# PHP Object/Array algorithm for a reservation system

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, object, calculation

The below code comes into my view for the $data object:

```
(
    [unallocated] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 25                    
                    [room] => to_be_allocated                    
                    [arrival_date] => 2020-10-01
                    [departure_date] => 2020-10-02                    
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 26                    
                    [room] => to_be_allocated              
                    [arrival_date] => 2020-11-01
                    [departure_date] => 2020-11-02                    
                )   
        )

    [allocated] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 14                    
                    [room] => 8                    
                    [arrival_date] => 2020-10-01
                    [departure_date] => 2020-10-17                    
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 21                    
                    [room] => 2                    
                    [arrival_date] => 2020-11-01
                    [departure_date] => 2020-11-03                    
                )
        )

    [all_rooms] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [room_no] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [room_no] => 2
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [room_no] => 3
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [room_no] => 4
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [room_no] => 5
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [room_no] => 6
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [room_no] => 7
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [room_no] => 8
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [room_no] => 9
                )

            [9] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [room_no] => 10
                )

            [10] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [room_no] => 11
                )
        )
)
```

There is a reservation system. 
"unalocated[0]" is a customer that wants to see what rooms could reserve. As you can see the arrival/departure date for "allocated" customers (they have a room allocated), the unalocated[0] should see all rooms except room nr 8 that is busy for its interval.

"unalocated[1]" could choose any room, because its interval is free.

On the back of that system is a select list that allows choosing a room depend on the interval you want (you will see just available rooms number). I populate my $data with all customer's requests, all reservations made already, and all rooms that exist.

I was trying a lot to think of an algorithm that shows all "unallocated" and for each of them to see just the available rooms depends on the arrival/departure and depends on the already "allocated" rooms arrival/departure, to not allow make an overbooking.

In other words: a hotel has 11 rooms. Few of them are already busy for the interval you want to accommodate and you should see a list of rooms available for your preferred interval.

My expected result is to iterate into "unallocated" and to see for every "id" an array that shows what rooms could be allocated, depends on the arrival/departure preferred but compared with what "allocated" customers already received for the same interval, to not happen overbooking (two different customers for the same period to receive the same room).

If somebody could help me I will say a BIG thank you! :)

Comment: I don't think this is a proper question for SO. You should give it a try and post your attempt with code and specific questions. I'll help you get started: _I think_ you can loop through the days in a given interval (for instance, 1st to last day of the month), and check each day. How many items in `allocated` start at o before, and end at or after each day (`arrival_date`<=day>=`departure_date`)? Is that amount smaller than the number of rooms? If so, there is availability. You may want to use a database, which will perform the search faster (the logic is the same).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have too many experiences, so I am lost. That code will loop thought "unallocated" customers, but then is not clear how I will receive a free room result for each customer: `foreach ($data['unallocated'] as $to_be_allocated){
 $to_be_allocated->id
}`